# how to ask VBA to select a non default option in a msg box from Microsoft Excel Security Notice?

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a Macro in VBA that processes other Excel files (a lot of them) with a for loop. Every time that a new one is opened, a Microsoft Excel Security Notice appears. There are two options:

```
Enable Macros
```

and

```
Disable Macros
```

where the latter one is the default option. I cannot set `always enable macros` in the settings as my company doesn't allow to modify this option. I was therefore wondering if there is a way to ask VBA to always select the `Enable Macro Option`.

Comment: Try setting 'Options -> Trust Center -> Trust Center Settings... -> Macro Settings' and tick `Trust Access to the VBA project object model' check box.  And try also adding your files locations to 'Trusted Locatons': 'Options -> Trust Center -> Trust Center Settings... -> Trusted Locations -> Add new location...'

Comment: @FaneDuru I added a trusted location and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Then, I will transform my comment in an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a few words, no, VBA cannot turn off the security notification.

The reason is quite clear; what's the point of it if anyone could simply turn it of through code? Any malicious macro would be allowed to run.

What you can do?

There a number of things you can try through the Trust Center settings.

1. Copy all the documents in a folder (or folders) and add the folder path(s) to the list of trusted locations.
2. If the documents are located in a network folder, enable the option which allows documents on a network to be trusted (you probably need to check your company's policy first).
3. Create a self signed certificate and sign all your VBA projects (not sure this will work if it's a self-signed cert).

Actually, since your company has a policy regarding macro security, I believe it's best to check with them before making any of the above changes.

Turning off the macro security is not a simple task, otherwise the security would be rubbish.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting

`'Options -> Trust Center -> Trust Center Settings... -> Macro Settings'` and tick `Trust Access to the VBA project object model' check box.

And try also adding your files locations to

`'Trusted Locatons': 'Options -> Trust Center -> Trust Center Settings... -> Trusted Locations -> Add new location'`...